# SSIS data transfer slows down after inserting few million rows

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am encountering this weird problem and any help will be really appreciated.

I have a single container in which I have 2 data flow task in my SSIS package, data transfer is very huge. Breakdown of problem.

- First Container is transferring from oracle to SQL around 130 million rows and it ran just fine and transfer the rows in about 40 to 60 mins which is very much acceptable.
- Now come the second part another data flow task is there that is transferring around 86 million rows from SQL server to SQL server(one table) only, the data transfer flies very fast till 60 70 million and after that it just dies out or crawls just like anything for next 10 million rows it took 15 hours, I am not able to understand why is it happening so?
- Table get truncated and then it gets loaded, I have tried increasing DataBuffer proeprties etc but with no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a single transaction and the transaction log is filling up. You can get 10-100x faster speeds if you move 10000 rows at a time. You may also try setting Maximum Insert Commit Size to 0 or try 5000 and go up to see the impact on performance. This is on the OLE DB Destination component. In my experience 10000 rows is the current magic number that seems to be the sweet spot but of course it is very dependent on how large the rows are, version of SQL Server and the hardware setup.

You should also look if there are indexes on the target table you can try dropping the indexes, loading the table and recreating the indexes.

Comment: Thanks! Will try these suggestions and will let you know can you suggest how to check if transaction log is filling up or not ?
My destination table has only one non clustered index will try disabling it and rebuilding it to see if that helps and Maximum Insert Commit Size to 0

Comment: Try changing the  Maximum Insert Commit Size to 10000 and see what happens.

Comment: If you are running 2012 and higher you can look at: SELECT  DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName ,
  database_id ,
  CAST(( total_log_size_in_bytes / 1048576.0 ) AS DECIMAL(10, 1))
                                                        AS TotalLogSizeMB ,
  CAST(( used_log_space_in_bytes / 1048576.0 ) AS DECIMAL(10, 1))
                                                        AS LogSpaceUsedMB ,
  CAST(used_log_space_in_percent AS DECIMAL(10, 1)) AS LogSpaceUsedPercent
FROM    sys.dm_db_log_space_usage;

Comment: Making Maximum insert Commit Size 0 gave a performance boost to the package but in Microsoft site it is mentioned that it is not a good practice to do, is there a drawback to that I have to run the package daily and has client sensitive data, any failure will cause huge issues.

Comment: If the step fails (regardless of what the Maximum Insert Commit Size is) you will have to rerun the package. Try different values and see how it effects execution time. According to MS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/ole-db-destination-editor-connection-manager-page 'The value of 0 indicates that all data is committed in a single batch after all rows have been processed.'

Answer (score 0):

What is your destination recovery model? Full/Simple, etc...

Are there any transformations between the source and destination? Try sending the source to a RowCount to determine the maximum speed your source can send data. You may be seeing a slowdown on the source side as well.

Is there any difference in content of the rows once you notice the slow down? For example, maybe the more recent rows have lots of text in a varchar(max) column that the early rows did not make use of.

Is your destination running on a VM?  If yes, have you pre-allocated the CPU and RAM?  SSIS is multi-threaded, but it won't necessarily use 100% of each core.  VM hosts may share the resources with other VMs because the SSIS VM is not reporting full usage of all of the resources.

Comment: Is there any difference in content of the rows once you notice the slow down? For example, maybe the more recent rows have lots of text in a varchar(max) column that the early rows did not make use of.

No there is no differece in content of the rows and no recent rows has lots of varchar etc

Comment: Is your destination running on a VM? If yes, have you pre-allocated the CPU and RAM? SSIS is multi-threaded, but it won't necessarily use 100% of each core. VM hosts may share the resources with other VMs because the SSIS VM is not reporting full usage of all of the resources

--I have no clue about how to check if SSIS package is running on which VM and to determine CPU and RAM usage any suggestion regarding this will be very helpful.I can login into the SQL server of destination table etc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

What is your destination recovery model? Full/Simple, etc... 
 
It is Full recovery model

Are there any transformations between the source and destination? Try sending the source to a RowCount to determine the maximum speed your source can send data. You may be seeing a slowdown on the source side as well. 

No transformation simple data transfer, have tried rowcount as suggested no bottleneck there.